# How to diagnose/manage DLL hell with InstallShield?

Tags: dll, installation, installshield, reference-counting

We use InstallShield to build installers for a number of very similar products, each of which has shared files parked in fixed directories underneath our vendor directory.  We have a DLL hell problem that I thought installers should handle.

Imagine products A and B both have file FOO, installed in directory D. FOO isn't necessarily a DLL; it can be any file.

In an ideal world, both copies of FOO are identical and when both products are installed FOO gets (overwritten) in D and everything is fine. And that's how it seems to work when everything is identical.

In practice, A and B may be from different generations, so in fact A has FOO variant A (FOO_a) and B has variant FOO_b.  Now only one of FOO_a or FOO_b will end up in D if both products are installed, and consequently one of A or B will be confused because the wrong file is there.

What I would have expected from installers (and InstallShield) is that for each product P installed on a system, that a reference counter would be kept somewhere (the registry?) regarding each installed file.  So when A is installed and FOO(_a) is placed, FOO is marked as belonging to A, and has reference count set to 1.  If B is now installed with an FOO_b identical to FOO_a, FOO should be marked as belonging also to B, and the reference count incremented.   If B is installed, and FOO_b is different than FOO_a, I'd expect the installer to complain that incompatible files FOO were being proposed for installation and the install should abort.  When a product is de-installed, I'd expect reference counters for each installed file to be decremented, and the installed file only removed when the reference count goes to zero.

That's not what InstallShield appears to do.  It simply smashes FOO into its target directory during an install.  This is in effect the same thing as DLL hell.  Is this the intended behavior of installers?  Of InstallShield? Of Windows?

We thought we looked for a way to ask InstallShield to manage this, but can't find anything.  I'd be pleased to have somebody tell where to look to configure this correctly.  Or is it that InstallShield can't/won't do this? [If so, why am I giving them money?]

Comment: What project type are you using,  InstallScript, Windows Installer?  This is critical in setting a discussion for best practices and expected behaviors.  Also I think it's unproductive to blame InstallShield for taking your money and not magically working for you.  It takes some thought and hard work to get this stuff right. (  I could blow your mind with what-ifs for XML files.. )

Comment: I'm not the actual guy doing the work, so I'll have to collect the "which type are you using" later.  I'm not blaming InstallShield; notice the IF.  The question being asked in fact assumes there's a way to do it, I'm just asking for confirmation and hint about where to explain that I want this to InstallShield.

Comment: This is why package managers exist... Silly Windows not providing one

Comment: -1 for previous comment. @Ira this site is for developers to help developers.  Having a middleman throw out all kinds of assumptions doesn't really help that process.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Don't assume too much about what I know, or my level of participation in this, or my personal experience with problem.  Before the current developer took ownership, I did most of the installer work.   That's different than I remember all the details, and I've not provided you with any "assumptions" to misguide you.  I said I'd get the facts so the conversation can stay rooted in reality.

Answer (score 2):

If variants of FOO are versioned and properly cumulative (this is key to all installation technologies that operate on shared locations), and if your component is shared, shares the same GUID in both products (if MSI), and shares the same installation location, then everything will work. As parts of that list of conditions are made untrue, various bad things can and will happen; some have workarounds, some are unrecoverable.

- If the installation location differs, little or none of this matters, unless both products end up searching in the same location for some other reason.
- If MSI, and the GUID differs (or the contents of the component differ), you've broken component rules. This may result in files not uninstalling at the final uninstall, unexpected changes in a repair, or other hard to predict results.
- If the file is not properly versioned, it is not possible to know when to replace it with the other one. It is likely in some ordering, a new install will end up running with an old version. This can be mitigated in an MSI with companion files, if another file has properly increasing versions.
- If the file is not cumulative with respect to versions, it is likely that a new version of the file will break the other consumer of it. In this scenario, you should not install  it to a shared location.

One size fits all does get a little messy sometimes, so generally the problem space is simplified to one that can be addressed. In this case the cost is that all installation authors have to follow some rules if they want well-defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly looking for a solution, use separate DLLs.  This is simple and reliable, and in fact it's easier to talk about (as you have demonstrated when you mention FOO_a and FOO_b).  It also avoids the error message, which is not helpful for your users.

Windows did have a reference counting scheme for shared DLLs, but it was by convention, so it was unreliable.  If you've ever had an uninstaller ask if you really want to delete a shared component, now you know why.

Comment: The files I'm talking about are not DLLs.  They are a wide variety of files, some text, some HTML, some binary, that our products expect/use; reference counting should for them, too.  ... Windows *did* have, or *still has* it?  Only for DLLs or for arbitrary files?  We're in control of our installers (I think), nobody has a reason to install something in our directories except for us, so if we use the same installer and it can manage reference counts, it is no longer by convention.

Comment: The reference counting was simply a registry entry with a counter.  There's no reason you can't (and *shouldn't*) do the same thing on your own.  However, IMHO, you would still be better off with separate spaces, rather than trying to share.  By sharing, you would be creating your own private equivalent of DLL hell.

Answer (score 1):

No one can possibly begin to answer your question without knowing what installation technology you are using.  InstallShield is a product that supports many different frameworks.

Windows only keeps track of shared references on DLL files. ( SharedDllCount ).  Windows Installer ( assuming you are even using it ) also keeps track of Compoent reference counts.

However, it should be noted (again *IF* you are using Windows Installer ) that the file costing process that decides to overwrite a file really has nothing to do with reference counts.  Reference counts come into play on uninstall.

Assuming you are using Windows Installer, take a look at:

[File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also look at:

[What happens if the component rules are broken?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This *is something Windows Installer and InstallShield know how to handle it assuming that you implement it correctly.  Any programming language can be misused and abused intentionally or not.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want the files to be common, why in the world are you placing them in the same directory? I would rather put them in different location. Now suppose your FOO_a is being used by many programs at the same version, then for FOO_b which is required by your new program and others that might be added later, add another similar common directory and name them using generation names or something.

Comment: Because in fact most of the time, the files *are* common and there's a lot of them; having separate copies seems pointless and having shared copies means if you see one in the shared directories, you know it is common to everything in those directories.  It is rare that shared files are different.  When they aren't different, the pieces overlay beatifully.   When the files vary (slow evolution over time), its OK to install in seperate directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in how the reference counting works if you are dealing with a pure MSI-based installer (it would help to know if A and B are Basic MSI or InstallScript projects). In any case, I would verify the components that contains FOO in the A and B install projects have it set as the key file, and have the Shared property set to Yes. That should cause the reference counting to be managed correctly.

Regarding what should happen when you run the installer and it has a newer version of a shared file, to my knowledge that depends mostly on whether the file has a version or not, whether it's a newer version, and properties like its last changed timestamp. If you are building an installer for B that contains FOO_b that is different from FOO_a, I'm not sure how InstallShield could know that it will break A (I could be wrong, maybe it can). One possible workaround is to use custom actions to check if FOO_b is different and if it is, make a copy of the existing one early in the install, then copy it back at the end of the process.

Comment: We don't have version numbers in the files in any form that Windows or InstallShield might have; we could arguably provide such version numbers to the installer for each file, but I'd be just fine with "binary file images don't match" as an incompatibility test.